# Issues processing my login script in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to create a login page for my node.js webpage. I have all of the mongodb pieces setup in the background. I have confirmed the accouont i am using to login with has been setup in my database.

However, i get the following error when I sign in:

```
var User = await User.findOne({
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findOne')
    at C:\Users\Mmart\Desktop\twitter\routes\loginRoutes.js:20:39
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Mmart\Desktop\twitter\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\Mmart\Desktop\twitter\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Mmart\Desktop\twitter\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Mmart\Desktop\twitter\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\Mmart\Desktop\twitter\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Mmart\Desktop\twitter\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\Mmart\Desktop\twitter\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\Mmart\Desktop\twitter\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:175:3)
    at router (C:\Users\Mmart\Desktop\twitter\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
```

This is my code:

```
router.post("/", async(req,res,next) => {

        var payload = req.body;

        if(req.body.logUsername && req.body.logPassword){
                var User = await User.findOne({
                        $or: [
                                { username: logUsername },
                                { email: logUsername }
                        ]
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                        payload.errorMessage = "something went wrong.";
                        res.status(200).render("login", payload);
                });
                if (user != null){
                        var result = bcrypt.compare(req.body.logPassword,user.Password);

                        if(result === true){
                                req.session.user = user;
                                return res.redirect("/");
                        }
                }
                payload.errorMessage = "login creds wrong.";
                return res.status(200).render("login", payload);
        }
        payload.errorMessage = "check values";
        res.status(200).render("login");
})
```

Comment: `var user = await User.findOne({`

Comment: Where did you create the `User`? I'll bet it's in another file and you forgot to import it.

Comment: could it be that .findOne is the issue? i read somewhere it might be depriciated.

Comment: Extending @KonradLinkowski answer, this is a typo error, you cannot declare the same variable as a model name. it should be in lowercase or choose another variable name.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I cannot post comments on other folks questions so this isn't a complete answer, but a question and possible answer.

Where is User defined? The line `var User = User.findOne(...)` looks like you're reassigning this anyway, but then after the try...catch, you check if

> *u*ser != null

with lowercase u, and since this is asynchrous code, are you overwriting this User object before the .method is called? In any case, the `if (user != null)` line is always going to fail as its not case insensitive, user and User are two different variables.

Comment: Someone else commented on the same thing whilst I was answering, @Konrad Linkowski also spotted the same typo. You need to make the variable assignment `var user = User.findOne(...)` with a lower case u